# Jogo de dois dados em Python

Tags: python

Não consegui fazer uma função que simula um jogo de dois dados e conta quantas vezes os dados foram
jogados até que sair numeros repetidos.

```
def dados():
dado1 = [random.randint(1,6)]
dado2 = [random.randint(1,6)]
if dado1 == dado2:
    return
```

Meu problema foi não saber o que retornar pra contar o numero de vezes que os daodos foram jogados até sair numeros repetido.

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, primeiro vou reescrever um pouco sua função:

```
import random  # biblioteca com funções prontas para gerar valores aleatórios


def lancar_dados():
   cont = 0  # aqui vamos contar quantas vezes os dados foram lançados
   while True:
      dado1 = [random.randint(1,6)]
      dado2 = [random.randint(1,6)]
      cont += 1
      if dado1 == dado2:
          return cont

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print(lancar_dados())
```

A função irá repetir até encontrar os valores iguais em `dado1` e `dado2`. E retorna a quantidade de vezes que os dois dados foram lançados.

Comment: você poderia adicionar o `import random`, pois alguns usuarios podem só copiar e colar e dar erro, assim fica mais facil para as outra pessoas :)